# Unicorn how to serialize parent folder and only specific children

Tags: unicorn, serialization

I need to serialize some custom WFFM save actions in my solution but would like to avoid needing to store each one in its own folder on the filesystem. Is there a way to indicate that I want to serialize `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions` and just one or two of its children and place the serialized children all into the same filesystem folder?

Comment: If i understand the question correctly, you want to exclude some child items from the parent item?
you can use exclude function that unicorn provides -  <include database="master" name="WFFMSaveActions" path="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions">
              <exclude path="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/xxx"/>
              <exclude path="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/YYY"/>
</include> This only applies to unicorn 3 and above.

Comment: Please could you post that as an answer!
FYI I'd prefer not to explicitly list all the things I don't want to serialize, if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unicorn 3 and above has an option to exclude child items under parent item. In your case you can use as below:

```
<include database="master" name="WFFMSaveActions" path="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions">
          <exclude path="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/xxx"/>
          <exclude path="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/YYY"/>
</include>
```

With unicorn 4 you can also exclude using namePatterns and templateIds:

```
<include database="master" name="WFFMSaveActions" path="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions">
          <exclude templateId="{3B4F2B85-778D-44F3-9B2D-BEFF1F3575E6}" />
          <exclude namePattern="^__Standard values$" />
</include>
```

This exclusion makes items not to be serialised by unicorn. More information about exclusions in unicorn can be found in this [blog post](https://kamsar.net/index.php/category/Unicorn/#Exclude_all_children_with_the_predicate)

Comment: I've seen the `pattern` attribute used on an include predicate for roles. Do you know if that works for items as well?

Comment: yes, according to kamsar blog post - https://kamsar.net/index.php/category/Unicorn/#Exclude_all_children_with_the_predicate

Comment: Ah cool, interesting stuff. I'm stuck with Unicorn 3 at the moment, so that's not an option unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this using Unicorn 3 is with `<exclude>` and `<except>` elements. This can be done like so:

```
<include name="xxxxxx.Foundation.CustomWffmFieldTypes.SaveActions"
         database="master"
         path="/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions">
  <exclude children="true">
    <except name="My Custom WFFM Save Action"/>
  </exclude>
</include>
```

This approach is described here: https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn/blob/ce1e7aacdb65d53cffa617f8a11106dd70b944e0/src/Unicorn.Tests/Predicates/TestConfiguration.xml